# Information about EpsonFp2Config tool

Tags: epson, fiscal-printer

would like to know what the test button of the EpsonFp2Config tool does because I am having problems with a service that if activated interrupts communication with the Epson fiscal printer and I would like to understand what this test does in order to solve the problem.
[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l0jg.png)

The operative system is Windows Server 2016 Standard

It does not do a simple ping because in both cases (whether the service is up or down) I can ping.

I have also tried port 9100 and it always gives me true with this command:

Test-NetConnection *IP Address* -port 9100

I think this test button tries to communicate with the fiscal printer, but how?